# Oauth2.0 attributes encrypted

Tags: javascript, encryption, oauth-2.0, apigee

I have to store some delicate information on the attributes for an Oauth token. Everything works fine but my client will like the attributes to be stored encrypted. Is there a configuration or a way to do this without pre and post processing them with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Storing is part of minting the token and the only way to encrypt data is with a call out to JS or Java.